# CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. Unity MAC Build issues

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, build, apk, dex

I am stuck, problems keep coming, never-ending! Please help.

I've got a game built using Unity. It's been facing many problems. I kept fixing one problem, another would pop up,

I've seen all guides I could find on google, I've tried lots of times using lots of versions of my project again and again to debug, but it's just not getting fixed.

Environment: 
Unity 5.5.5 (I'm using this version because otherwise, my project will be having much more issues), 
jdk1.8.0_171
android-ndk-r13b

It just keeps getting failed to repackage (dex issues), there are duplicates apparently, and when I delete some of them, then other's will have problems, perhaps dependencies issues. 
So, basically one thing gets fixed, other thing pops up!

**here is the code**

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
/Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.0/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "/Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.arch.lifecycle:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.customtabs:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.admob.impl.license:com.google.android.gms.admob:com.google.android.gms.admob.license:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.common.license:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.gass.license:com.google.android.exoplayer2.core:com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash:com.facebook.android:com.facebook.android:com.facebook.applinks:com.facebook.common:com.facebook.core:com.facebook.login:com.facebook.messenger:com.facebook.places:com.facebook.share:android.support.v7.recyclerview:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.v4:com.unity3d.ads.android -S "
    /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.cardview-v7-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.customtabs-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-core-ui-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-core-utils-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-fragment-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-26.1.0/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-12.0.1/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-license-12.0.1/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-12.0.1/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-lite-license-12.0.1/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-12.0.1/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-license-12.0.1/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-gass-12.0.1/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/com.google.android.gms.play-services-gass-license-12.0.1/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/exoplayer-core/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/exoplayer-dash/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-wrapper-7.12.1/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-wrapper-release/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-common/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-login/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-messenger/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-share/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/recyclerview-v7/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-compat/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-core-ui/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-core-utils/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/support-v4/res" -S "/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res"  

stderr[
/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-common/res/values/values.xml:72: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar'.

/Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-common/res/values/values.xml:77: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.  




]
stdout[
Configurations:
(default)

Files:
drawable/unityads_background_button_pause.xml
Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_background_button_pause.xml
drawable/unityads_icon_play.xml
Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_icon_play.xml
drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_base.xml
Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_base.xml
drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_triangle.xml
        Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_triangle.xml
      drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_waves.xml
        Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_waves.xml
      layout/unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml
        Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/layout/unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml
      layout/unityads_button_pause.xml
        Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/layout/unityads_button_pause.xml
      layout/unityads_view_video_paused.xml
        Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/layout/unityads_view_video_paused.xml
      layout/unityads_view_video_play.xml
        Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/layout/unityads_view_video_play.xml
      values/strings.xml
        Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/values/strings.xml
      AndroidManifest.xml
        Src: () AndroidManifest.xml   


Resource Dirs:
Type drawable
drawable/unityads_background_button_pause.xml
Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_background_button_pause.xml
        drawable/unityads_icon_play.xml
          Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_icon_play.xml
        drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_base.xml
          Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_base.xml
        drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_triangle.xml
          Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_triangle.xml
        drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_waves.xml
          Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/drawable/unityads_icon_speaker_waves.xml
      Type layout
        layout/unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml
          Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/layout/unityads_button_audio_toggle.xml
        layout/unityads_button_pause.xml
          Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/layout/unityads_button_pause.xml
        layout/unityads_view_video_paused.xml
          Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/layout/unityads_view_video_paused.xml
        layout/unityads_view_video_play.xml
          Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/layout/unityads_view_video_play.xml
      Type values
        values/strings.xml
          Src: () /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/unityads/res/values/strings.xml
    Including resources from package: /Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar
    applyFileOverlay for drawable
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_send_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_send_icon_blue.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_send_icon_white.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_send_button_icon.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_bubble_large_blue.png
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_bubble_large_white.png
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_bubble_small_blue.png
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_bubble_small_white.png
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_blue_bg_round.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_blue_bg_selector.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_send_round_shadow.png
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_white_bg_round.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_white_bg_selector.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_login_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_login_logo.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_login_silver_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_background.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_bottomnub.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_topnub.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_black_xout.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_background.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_bottomnub.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_topnub.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_blue_xout.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_auth_dialog_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_auth_dialog_cancel_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_auth_dialog_header_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_icon.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_icon_blue.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_icon_white.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_like_icon_selected.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_close.png
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_favicon_blue.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_action_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_bg.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_bg_low.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_bg_low_normal.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_bg_normal.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_bg_normal_pressed.9.png
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_icon_background.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_tile_bg.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notify_panel_notification_icon_bg.png
    trying overlaySet Key=app_icon.png
    applyFileOverlay for layout
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_send_blue_large.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_send_blue_round.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_send_blue_small.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_send_white_large.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_send_white_round.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=messenger_button_send_white_small.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_tooltip_bubble.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_activity_layout.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_login_fragment.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_media_action.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_media_cancel_action.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_big_media.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_big_media_custom.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_big_media_narrow_custom.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_lines_media.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_media.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_media_custom.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_action.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_action_tombstone.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_custom_big.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_icon_group.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_part_chronometer.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=notification_template_part_time.xml
    applyFileOverlay for anim
    applyFileOverlay for animator
    applyFileOverlay for interpolator
    applyFileOverlay for transition
    applyFileOverlay for xml
    applyFileOverlay for raw
    applyFileOverlay for color
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_send_button_text_color.xml
    trying overlaySet Key=com_facebook_button_text_color.xml
    applyFileOverlay for menu
    applyFileOverlay for font
    applyFileOverlay for mipmap
    Processing image: res/drawable-ldpi/app_icon.png
    Processing image: res/drawable-mdpi/app_icon.png
    Processing image: res/drawable-hdpi/app_icon.png
    Processing image: res/drawable-xhdpi/app_icon.png
        (processed image res/drawable-ldpi/app_icon.png: 99% size of source)
    Processing image: res/drawable-xxhdpi/app_icon.png
        (processed image res/drawable-mdpi/app_icon.png: 99% size of source)
    Processing image: res/drawable-xxxhdpi/app_icon.png
        (processed image res/drawable-hdpi/app_icon.png: 99% size of source)
    Processing image: /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-common/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/com_facebook_button_icon_blue.png
        (processed image /Users/MyUserName/Large Dstp Fls Fldrs/apps/AppCategory1/EXAMPLEAPP/T<message truncated>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks

Comment: not quite sure how, but it got solved eventually,